# In which thing OS is developed/written?

Tags: development, design

If it is another OS then how was the first OS made?

Answer (score 3):

The short version is this:

- elementary is based on Ubuntu.
- Ubuntu is based on Debian.
- Debian was one of the first Linux distros.

Each distro takes the foundation laid by the previous one and uses it to build something new.

For the long version, see [the history of Linux](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2011/08/march-of-the-penguin-ars-looks-back-at-20-years-of-linux/) and [the first ten years of Ubuntu](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/10/ten-years-of-ubuntu-how-linuxs-beloved-newcomer-became-its-criticized-king/). For more on how elementary OS came to be, see [Wired's article on elementary OS](https://www.wired.com/2013/11/elementaryos/).